# Programmatically sending mule message (formerly: Accessing mule http endpoint from java)

Tags: java, mule

Scroll towards the end for the solution to the topic's problem. The original question was asking for a somewhat different thing.

---

As a part of a larger process, I need to fetch and link two related sets of data together. The way that the data is retrieved(dynamics crm, n:n relationships..) forces us retrieve the second set of the data again so that it will have all the necessary information. During a part of larger transformation of this data, I would like to access the http endpoint that is used to fetch the data from the crm, retrieve the second set of data and process it. I can get the endpoint through DefaultEndPointFactory like so:

```
DefaultEndpointFactory def = new DefaultEndpointFactory();
def.getInboundEndpoint("uri").getConnector;
```

But there is no method to actually send the mulemessage.

Solved:
*The problem is that you can not set inbound properties on the MuleMessage, and the flow is depending on some of those to function(path, query params etc).*

It seems you are able to inbound scoped properties with this:

```
m.setProperty("test", (Object)"test", PropertyScope.INBOUND);
```

Is there a way to make this approach work, or an alternative way to access the flow? I tried using mulecontext to get the flow:

```
muleContext.getRegistry().lookupFlowConstruct("myflow");
```

But it did not contain anything that looked useful.

---

**Solution:**
As David Dossot suggested in a comment of his answer, I was able to solve this with muleClients `request` method.

```
muleContext.getClient().request(url, timeout);
```

Then constructing the url as usual with GET parameters etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about what you're trying to achieve but anyway, the correct way of using Mule transports from Java code is to use the [MuleClient](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/client/MuleClient.html), which you can access with `muleContext.getClient()`.

For example, the `send` method allow you to pass a properties map that are automatically added to the inbound scope. Behind the scene, Mule takes care of creating the endpoint needed for the operation.

Regarding the flow: what are you trying to do with it? Invoke it?

Comment: Yes. Basically I am trying to simulate what would happen should there be a normal request to the endpoint, but this request would not come from a browser, but from java code.

Comment: So use the `request` operation of the Mule client to call the flow's inbound endpoint over HTTP, that'll be the closest to what a browser would do.